# Correct way to wait after click once clicked then enable again? Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I looked at many of the same question as mine and I tried to implement them into my code, but no luck.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // when the user clicks on like
    $('.icon-wrapper').on('click', function(){
        setTimeout(function() {

                }, 5200);
        var postid = $(this).data('id');
            $post = $(this);

        $.ajax({

            url: 'user_profiles.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'liked': 1,
                'postid': postid
            },

            success: function(response){

                $post.parent().find('span.likes_count').text(response);

                $post.addClass('hide');
                $post.siblings().removeClass('hide');
                $post.siblings().addClass('anim');
                $post.removeClass('anim');



            }
        });
    });


// when the user clicks on unlike
    $('.icon-appear').on('click', function(){
        setTimeout(function() {

                }, 5200);
        var postid = $(this).data('id');
        $post = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'user_profiles.php',
            type: 'post',
            data: {
                'unliked': 1,
                'postid': postid
            },
            success: function(response){

                $post.parent().find('span.likes_count').text(response);
                $post.siblings().removeClass('anim');
                $post.addClass('anim');
                $post.addClass('hide');
                $post.siblings().removeClass('hide');


            }
        });
    });
});
```

**The code above is the one that doesn't work when I insert `setTimeout`**

```
    var $iconWrapper = $(".icon-wrapper");
$iconWrapper.on('click', function() {
  var _this = $(this);
  if (_this.hasClass('anim')) _this.removeClass('anim');
  else {
    _this.addClass('anim');
    _this.css('pointer-events', 'none');
    setTimeout(function() {
      _this.css('pointer-events', '');
    }, 3200);
  }
})
```

This one works but not as well as it should. When I got to like, it doesn't delay the like, it delays the unlike instead.

When I go to like something, no action takes place. I am trying to prevent the button from being push multiple times quickly.  **I am still learning Javascript so I gladly appreciate any response/answer!**

Comment: You asked this same question within last several hours. Stop duplicating questions

Comment: Maybe a confusion?

Comment: Or perhaps this is homework and someone else asked same thing? The issues are identical right down to using `'pointer-events'` inside the `setTimout`

Comment: I'm not sure, but I got this from codepen and I just needed some help on it. @charlietfl